# WPF Image with Remote Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to load an image into my Silverlight project and I have the following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Image Height="150" Width="200" Source="http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Images/rain.gif" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image control in Silverlight only supports PNG and JPEG, not GIF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(VS.95).aspx

Comment: So what should I use instead?

Comment: @Spencer Try implementing a valueconverter to convert the GIF content into a supported format?

Comment: Your easiest bet would be to use a different file format.  But if you insist on using GIF, one of the silverlight program managers wrote on how he used an external framework to display an animated gif in silverlight (near the bottom).  I haven't personally tried it though: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jstegman/archive/2008/06/08/sample-updates-for-beta-2.aspx